# laravel share session / cookie data between laravel and legacy PHP (subdomain)

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, session-cookies

I'm running a laravel app as some kind of main application on domain.com, and on a subdomain app2.domain.com I run another (not laravel based) PHP application, how can I share cookie / session data between two domains?

I would need to share some kind of the user model property of the logged in user from the laravel application to my app2.domain.com application.

Laravel session is already stored inside redis, so it would be easy to get access to the driver itself.

Maybe someone has implemented this already in the past / any examples on how to share session / cookie data between laravel and a another subdomain based PHP app?

Comment: See https://github.com/stechstudio/laravel-raw-sessions. That will get Laravel using native php sessions. Not sure about the separate subdomain part though.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work with the following procedure:
Make sure the environment variables in the .env for laravel installations have the same identical settings as the Php application: (You have to make adjustments to your standalone too accordingly but I can't tell you the code without seeing it)

```
#APP_KEY is used to encrypt the session data so must be the same and the standalone must use laravels algorithm of hashing it
APP_KEY=base64:'YOUR KEY ' 
#SESSION_COOKIE must be the same, this is normally not set and defaults to APP_NAME+"_session' which is a problem if your apps have different names
SESSION_COOKIE=laravel_session #Same for php standalone
#The SESSION_DOMAIN defaults to null which causes the CORS scope to limit to the subdomain level, in my testing must start with leading dot.
SESSION_DOMAIN=.rootdomain.com #Same for php standalone
```

In my case I also changed the hard coded config/session.php variables to:

```
'http_only'=>false,//not necessary but helpful in such applications
'samesite'=>'lax',//newer laravel will allow you to set 'none' but beware of security issues
```